# PHP library/class for extracting information from variety of file formats

Tags: php, file

I'm looking for a `PHP` class/library that would dynamically extract information from files without any manual work required. For instance:

**any type of file:** size, name, path, extension, mime type, md5sum...
**images:** width, height, colors used...
**archives:** compression level, list of files contained in archive...
**video/audio files:** duration, metadata...
**documents:** number of words / characters / pages...

I'm not looking for a frontend like these [`PHP`-based file managers/explorers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209103/what-is-the-best-web-based-file-explorer), what I want is a library that can return as much information as possible from as many file formats as possible (I had a look at re-using some code from these file managers/explorers, but it can only be few lines here and there, as what I'm looking for is usually mangled in the file manager/explorer's logic).

So far all I have found are wrappers and small implementations that focus on 1 type of file (e.g. [`FileInfo`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.fileinfo.php) for general purpose, [`ImageMagick`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/api.php#php) for images, [`Zend_Service_LiveDocx`](http://www.phplivedocx.org/articles/pdf-generation-with-zend-framework/) for documents...) but would like to ask the question anyway just to make sure I'm not missing anything major.

**Are there PHP classes/libraries already available out there that can retrieve a lot of info about many different file formats?**

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to bodge together some PEAR libraries:

http://pear.php.net/package/MIME_Type

http://pear.php.net/package/Image_Remote

http://pear.php.net/packages.php?catpid=9&catname=File+System